# Void withCheckedThrowingContinuation Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Tags: swift

I'm unable to get `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` to compile when there’s no return type. For example:

```swift
    public
    func
    write(toDevice inDeviceID: Int, atAddress inAddr: Int, value inVal: Float)
        async
        throws
    {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation
               // ^ Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
        { inCont in
            self.workQ.async
            {
                do
                {
                    self.deviceID = inDeviceID
                    try self.write(address: inAddr, value: inVal)
                    inCont.resume()
                }
                
                catch (let e)
                {
                    inCont.resume(throwing: e)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

A version that returns works just fine:

```swift
    public
    func
    readRegister(address inAddr: Int, fromDevice inDeviceID: Int)
        async
        throws
        -> UInt16
    {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation
        { inCont in
            self.workQ.async
            {
                do
                {
                    self.deviceID = inDeviceID
                    let r = try self.readRegister(address: inAddr)
                    inCont.resume(returning: r)
                }
                
                catch (let e)
                {
                    inCont.resume(throwing: e)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As I was writing this I found being explicit like this works:

```swift
    public
    func
    write(toDevice inDeviceID: Int, atAddress inAddr: Int, value inVal: Float)
        async
        throws
    {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation
        { (inCont: CheckedContinuation<Void, Error>) -> Void in
            self.workQ.async
            {
                do
                {
                    self.deviceID = inDeviceID
                    try self.write(address: inAddr, value: inVal)
                    inCont.resume()
                }
                
                catch (let e)
                {
                    inCont.resume(throwing: e)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I filed a bug with Apple.

Comment: I have to explicitly specify the type as well

Comment: at least it's cumbersome. Not sure if it's really a bug. As a side note: The code formatting you are using looks very different. Have never seen something like this. I would strongly consider using some more standard styleguide (if this is not your company's standard or something)

Comment: @laka I format my code so it's easily read top-to-bottom. The "standard" style sucks.

Answer (score 12):

If you use `return` before `try await` it should work. I don't really understand why, because return shouldn't be needed in this case but it works on my end.

```
public
func
write(toDevice inDeviceID: Int, atAddress inAddr: Int, value inVal: Float)
    async
    throws
{
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation
    { inCont in
        self.workQ.async
        {
            do
            {
                self.deviceID = inDeviceID
                try self.write(address: inAddr, value: inVal)
                inCont.resume()
            }
            
            catch (let e)
            {
                inCont.resume(throwing: e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yours is the working solution!

Comment: This is elegantly inferring Void from the function signature, nice!

Answer (score 8):

I thought I would add another example

```
extension Something {
    public func sync() async throws {
        // The swift compiler demands that we be explicit where there is no return type.
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (continuation: CheckedContinuation<Void, Error>) -> Void in
            self.sync { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let entry):
                    continuation.resume(with: .success(entry))
                case .failure(let error):
                    continuation.resume(with: .failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Xcode can now wrap your closure based function with async/await continuations.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unless Apple fixes this on their side, found a bit more concise approach:

```
public
func
write(toDevice inDeviceID: Int, atAddress inAddr: Int, value inVal: Float)
    async
    throws
{
    let _: () = try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation
    // ^ Letting it know the type we expect
    { inCont in
        self.workQ.async
        {
            do
            {
                self.deviceID = inDeviceID
                try self.write(address: inAddr, value: inVal)
                inCont.resume()
            }
            
            catch (let e)
            {
                inCont.resume(throwing: e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```